# how to compare 2 files in bash and redirect a specific value to a new file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a 2 files, say `test` and `test1`, with the following output:

```
test                      test1
abcd;india                abcd
efgh;india
ijkl;us
mnop;us
```

What's the correct way to compare `test` and `test1` and and redirect the region information from test file to a new file say `test2`?

```
test2 expected output
india
```

Comment: What efforts did you make at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$2; next }($1 in a){ print a[$1] }' test test1
```

To save in output file redirect like below

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$2; next }($1 in a){ print a[$1] }' test test1 > test2
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F';' '                            # call awk set field separator as ;
           FNR==NR{                    # first file "test"
                a[$1]=$2;              # a is array, 
                                       # $1 (col1) is array key
                                       # $2 (col2) is array value
                next                   # stop processing further go to next line
           }
          ($1 in a){                   # here we read file "test1"
                                       # if array a has index which is 1st column from test1 file
                print a[$1]            # print array a value   
         }' test test1
```

Comment: I'm sure I'd told you this before. Kindly do not feed easy answers to questions that show zero research effort just for harvesting rep

Comment: works like a charm . is it possible to check the case as well whether lower or upper??

Comment: @gosatriani Please add all requirements to the OP, not in the comments.

Comment: @Inian sorry I remember, but seeing OP's reputation I thought probably newbie, so my bad

Comment: @gosatriani it looks for exact keyword, hence case will be considered, it will not match "abcd" with "Abcd"

Comment: @gosatriani you mean case insensitive ? if so hint left for you, make all `$1` to `tolower($1)`, so that all keys will be stored in lowercase

Comment: @json it's not bug, to skip remaining statements while reading first file next keyword is used

Comment: @janos  with `next` keyword `($1 in a){ ....}` will not be executed while awk reads first file

Answer (score 0):

you can use diff command to compare test and test1

diff test test1 > test2

Comment: Did that produce the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If `test1` only has one entry, you could simplify:

```
$ awk -F\; -v p=$(<test1) '$1==p{print $2}' test
india
```

Explained:

- `awk` obvious
- `-F\;` set the field separator
- `-v p=$(<test1)` read the search word from file `test1` to awk variable `p`
- `'$1==p{print $2}'` if the search word is in the first field, print the second field
- `test` the file